# Copying more than 1 page sized buffers from kernel space to user space using sysfs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

I have created a sysfs entry with store and show functions. I'd like to use show function to copy buffers of size > PAGE_SIZE from the kernel space to userspace.

I am able to currently copy buffers of size PAGE_SIZE from/to kernel space to/from userspace respectively.

Any tips on how we can do it will be really helpful. Can we loop this show function in any possible way?

Also, In case above is not possible. Can you please suggest alternative ways to do the same thing? (which can be done really quickly)

Comment: Use binary attributes instead of regular attributes.

Comment: I assume you are talking about device attributes that we create with store and show functions. Can you please elaborate on what binary attributes are?

Comment: I mean `struct bin_attribute`. Instead of optional `show` and `store` methods, binary attributes have optional  `read` and `write` methods (and also an optional `mmap` method). The `read` and `write` methods have offset and count parameters. If you have something that you want to behave like a random access file, a binary attribute should be suitable, If you have something that you want to behave like a sequential file or pipe, a binary attribute probably isn't suitable. Binary attributes can be included in attribute groups along with regular attributes.

Comment: So using bin_attribute you are saying I will be able to copy larger buffers from kernel space to userspace? Can you please elaborate and post the same as an answer. Will be really helpful if you can also share some code on how I can use these bin_attributes for large buffers using bin_attributes.

Comment: Using bin_attribute, you will be able to copy larger buffers from kernel space to userspace, but it will be done via an intermediate kernel buffer in PAGE_SIZE (or less) chunks (the binary attribute `read` and `write` methods use a kernel buffer like the regular attribute `show` and `store` methods). The `read` and `write` methods are random access, so need to take the passed in position into account. I've never written any code that uses binary attributes, but there are plenty of examples of their usage in the kernel source code you can examine, for example "drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c".

Comment: Alright, Thanks. Will give it a try,